# Android save activity dynamically created layout in onPause

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

So I'd like to save temporarily my Activity layout. My layout is created in a LinearLayout, by adding children like `ll.addView(btn);`
But when I go to another Intent, and that Intent finishes, all the added buttons disappear. How can I prevent this?

Comment: why do u want to do like this ?

Comment: Data are received from a service. When user selects data -> activity displaying them -> back to data selection

Comment: Despite all the answers here, you should check, why your activity is recreated.

Comment: @JacksOnF1re it is not recreated. It's just paused, and it's state is lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to implement `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` and `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)`.

In `onSaveInstanceState` you store the information needed to create the views dynamically in the bundle.

In `onRestoreInstanceState` you get this information from the bundle and recreate the dynamic layout.

Something like:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
  bundle.putString("key", "value"); // use the appropriate 'put' method
  // store as much info as you need
  super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(bundle);
  bundle.getString("key"); // again, use the appropriate 'get' method.
  // get your stuff
  // add views dynamically
}
```

Alternatively, you can restore your layout's dynamic views from the `onCreate` method instead of the `onRestoreInstanceState` method. You decide what's best for you.

Comment: `onCreate` is not an alternative for `onRestoreInstanceState`.

Comment: @BirendraSingh It is. From the docs: "Both the onCreate() and onRestoreInstanceState() callback methods receive the same Bundle that contains the instance state information." https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#saras

Comment: From the same page **Instead of restoring the state during `onCreate()` you may choose to implement `onRestoreInstanceState()`, *which the system calls after the `onStart()` method***. The logic will break if someone implements `onStart()` which initializes some state variables.

Comment: If activity is paused then `onCreate()` is not going to help.

Comment: @BirendraSingh So? It is still an alternative. Whether it's the best way to do it will depend on the case in question. Sometimes, restoring the instance state in `onCreate()` is a way to avoid redundant code. If `onCreate` wasn't meant to be used to restore the instance state, this possibility would never exist in the framework, specially if you consider that `onCreate(Bundle)` and `onRestoreInstanceState` were both available since API Level 1. Again, choosing `onCreate` or `onRestoreInstanceState` to restore data will depend on the situation.

Comment: and the title of the question explicitly contains the word `onPause`. Finally I don't agree as per my definition of **Alternative.**

Comment: @BirendraSingh Besides, if the Activity is just paused, then there is no need to save or restore the instance state. If `restoreInstanceState` is called, it means the Activity was destroyed, thus, `onCreate` will also be called.

Comment: @BirendraSingh Well, you can have your opinion, but the docs agree with me. "Most implementations will simply use onCreate(Bundle) to restore their state, but it is sometimes convenient to do it here (referring to onRestoreInstaceState)". Which means that yes, onCreate is an alternative. I rest my case. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

Answer (score 1):

```
You can make use of onSaveInstanceState to save the view and 
onRestoreInstanceState to retrieve the saved view.

private String someVarB;

...

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putString("btn_added", "true");
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    someVarB = savedInstanceState.getString("btn_added");

    if(someVarB.equalsIgnoreCase(true))
    {
         ll.addView(btn); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent an Activity's contents from always updating each time you call it by using Intent() action, go to the Manifest file and add a tag to the activity named `android:launchMode="singleTask".
Here is an example

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TranscluscentBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: This will create another launcher for the activity, as far as I know

Comment: No, I copied this snippet from my project where launch mode is used on my MainActivity (Which is also the launcher activity). All I'm explaining is the android:launchMode="singleTask"